# Change telegram bot owner

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

We have created telegram bot which has many difficult operations. Bot was created by one developer using his phone number. Is it possible change bot's owner or add another user as admin to bot?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Recently, the function of transferring the bot to another person appeared.

[image]

Comment: To transfer the bot you have to be able to attach a contact and as of 10 March 2022 you can't do that on MacOS, only on the phone

Answer (score 7):

One of possible solutions (most simple as I wonder) is in the creation a **new bot** with **same username**. So only need to **delete your old bot**, create new and **change bot token** in your program code.

---

*Note that it's possible **only if the old bot's owner collaborates**. To prevent similar situations your company need to create one telegram account for creating bots, channels etc., without ties to concrete persons.*

---

UPD 2020

Telegram teem finally did the trick and added the changing ownership feature. Bingo. But this will not help if you can't ping an owner, same.

Comment: Exact outline: `..company need to create one telegram account for creating bots, channels etc., without ties to concrete persons...`

Answer (score 5):

Please see [Bekorchi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64805629/5201431), it's possible to transfer bots since 2020 October.

### Out-dated:

Not possible to transfer by @BotFather command at this time (2017 July).

You can contact human supporter [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport), they may have permission to transfer that.

Comment: thank you for answer, @BotSupport said this operation is not supported at the moment

Answer (score 4):

the developer can delete all of other bots and channel and chat history, then use **CHANGE NUMBER** in setting and transfer the bot to new virgin mobile number.
after this, the developer can login again with his/her own mobile number to telegram as new account.

Answer (score 0):

Nowdays (October 2022) you can transfer bot ownership. But you can't do it via web version

[image: changing bot ownership via web interface]

(see, Yes option is disabled)

Yet, you can do it via mobile version:

[image: changing bot ownership via mobile interface]

but you should fulfill following demands:

[image: telegram security demands]

P.S. If you have enough rights please move my note to a comment of the proper answer